# Keep Fixed Data row fixed on mutliple pages when deployed

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Tablix member that is FixedData and works fine in preview mode.

The problem is once deployed the Fixed Data only shows on the first page, the next page it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **enable the advanced mode** in the grouping panes.

[image]

Once you enable the advanced mode you will see static groups in your grouping pane. when you **select static group** you will notice that corresponding cell in the table will be highlighted.

[image]

Goto the desired cell by selecting the appropriate Static Group. In the **properties window** of that static group set **RepeatOnNewPage to True** and **KeepWithgroup to After**

[image]

Now you are all set to show data row on multiple pages.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I experienced something similar its rather strange but SSRS play funny games sometimes.

1. I deleted the Data Source and created again and it started working
   God knows why but it worked for me.
2. Another thing sometimes If
       screen display settings are set to medium some times the report data
       doesnt display but when you export from the reportviewer to some
       excel or so you can actually find all the data.
3. One last thing try it in a different browser preferably IE.