# SSRS 2008 Nested Table Print Header on every page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, dynamics-nav

what I want to do is the following. I have 2 Tablix, the second one is nested in the first one and prints detailed information (it's a document for a sales quote from dynamics nav).

Like this:

```
Tablix1
    Header1
    Header2
      Body
        Tablix2
          Header
          Body
```

No I want to print the Header1 on the first page of my document and the header2 on all following pages. The idea behind this is to have separate headers for page 1 and all following pages.

When I print my quote now the header1 gets printed but the header2 doesn't. I was hoping to at least get the header1 printed on every page. Is this possible somehow? I already set all properties correctly (I think :-)): RepeatRowHeaders=True

I don't want to use the normal report header because it is of fixed height which would get me in trouble after page 1.

If you know any other way to achieve this please don't hesitate to give me a hint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Jan

Comment: Can you show current output and sample data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this...the data comes from Dynamics NAV, so I don't have a query or such. Can you clarify what you mean? I'm (obviously) not very familiar with SSRS.

Comment: You already created an SSRS report I assume. So can you take a screenshot of current report output and tell what is wrong with that.

Comment: Sorry I can't upload images because of my reputation. I uploaded the files to my dropbox-account: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76209248/ReportDesignIssues/Report%20Design.pdf) It's a PDF containing all screenshots...thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You probably need to enable advanced mode. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189564/keep-fixed-data-row-fixed-on-mutliple-pages-when-deployed/19190771#19190771

Comment: Hi Anup, thanks for your reply. I just tried that, but the properties where already set the way your link suggests.

Comment: Ok, now I got it working somehow. I set the fixedData-property to true on every line of my table (including details) and now my header(s) get repeated on every page. But now I want to show different headers on page 1 and the following pages. I already found out how to show the "big" header only on the first page but then my "smaller" header for the second page gets printed on first page too. Anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

your tablix has four sections separated by the dotted lines traversing it.
Did you put both of you column/row headers in the top part of your tablix?
If so, you only have to go to Tablix propieties dialog, under general section check Repeat header columns/row on each page.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. I added my headers using right-click on the body and chosing option "Out of group - Above" (sorry if this is not the correct translation, my version is german). But yes, I got dotted lines and when I right click on my header I can't chose the option above again. The repeat row header option is already set.

Comment: I tried to set the option repeat column header now and now the report repeats the header of tablix 2 on every page (as long as I'm in this data-area at least) but I want to repeat the header from tablix1...